# WPF: how to display enum property values in VS2008 XAML editor intellisense?

Tags: wpf, xaml, enums, properties, intellisense

I created a WPF custom control with a dependency property of an enum type.

I want the user of that control when editing the XAML in VS to see the optional values of the enum in the intellisense window.

Does anyone know how it can be done?

Comment: checkout this link. You will idea about how to do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857967/using-enum-as-a-dependency-property-in-wpf

Answer (score 1):

I believe it will work if you add an "XmlnsDefinition" attribute to the assembly containing the control. By the way, I ran into problems with this when trying to reference the control in the same project.

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked also here:

[How can I get IntelliSense to auto-complete an enum on a custom/user control in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596089/how-can-i-get-intellisense-to-auto-complete-an-enum-on-a-custom-user-control-in-x/596145)

There is an answer but it's not marked, maybe you can try the suggestion and come back with the result of your test.

Comment: I've posted some steps to get this to work in the link above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596089