# How can I get IntelliSense to auto-complete an enum on a custom/user control in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF: how to display enum property values in vs2008 xaml editor intellisense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419802/wpf-how-to-display-enum-property-values-in-vs2008-xaml-editor-intellisense)

In XAML if I am defining the Orientation property for a StackPanel, IntelliSense brings up the Orientation enum.  If I'm defining my own control with a DependencyProperty based on an enum, is there a way to get IntelliSense to bring up the enum?

Enum:

```
public enum MyEnum { Foo, Bar }
```

DependencyProperty in control:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyEnumValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MyEnumValue",
        typeof(MyEnum),
        typeof(MyControl),
        new UIPropertyMetadata());

public MyEnum MyEnumValue
{
    get { return (MyEnum)GetValue(MyEnumValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyEnumValueProperty, value); }
}
```

EDIT:

Giving the answer to "Daniel Pratt", because he pointed me in the right direction.  I'd have preferred a code example.

To get this to work:

1. Add the XmlnsDefinition attribute to AssemblyInfo.cs

   [assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.your-company.com/wpf/", "YourNamespace")]
2. In the XAML source where the control will be defined add an xmlns entry for it

   xmlns:control="http://schemas.your-company.com/wpf/"
3. Then presto, you can add the control and IntelliSense will bring up the enum values

Answer (score 0):

try something like [this](http://vyasashutosh.blogspot.com/2007/05/providing-custom-intellisense-in-vsnet.html) or use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)