# Exposing properties of UserControl on tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

Consider this UserControl...

```
public partial class Fubar : UserControl
{
    public enum StateOfThings
    {
        FU,
        BAR,
        FUBAR
    }

    public StateOfThings State { get; set; }
}
```

Are you able to expose the `State` property like so...

```
<uc:Fubar runat="server" State="StateOfThings.FU" />
```

... Or do I have to create a CustomControl, or settle with changing custom properties in the code-behind?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get IntelliSense to auto-complete an enum on a custom/user control in XAML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596089/how-can-i-get-intellisense-to-auto-complete-an-enum-on-a-custom-user-control-in)

Answer (score 0):

You would want to create a property and have the Enum as the type of that property.

```
public partial class Fubar : UserControl
{
    public property StateOfThings State { get; set; }
}

public enum StateOfThings
{
    FU,
    BAR,
    FUBAR
}

<uc:Fubar runat="server" State="FU" />
```