# How to enable XAML intellisense for a type

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, intellisense

The primary purpose of WPF custom control is, It should accept an `Enum` type and generate radio buttons in UI for the selection.

That contains two `DependencyProperty`s

1. EnumType : Type - to generation radio buttons.
2. SelectedValue : Object - To represent the current selection

By default, it shall use the enum names as the `DisplayText` for each radio button and there is an attached property which allows user to override UI names.

The attached property accepts a static resource of type `EnumUICollection` which is inherited from `ObservableCollection<EnumUI>`. The `EnumUI` type consists of two properties

1. EnumValue : object or TEnumType
2. DisplayText : string

Below is the creation of static resource.

```
<custControl:EnumUINameCollection x:Key="daysUINamesOverridden" EnumType="{x:Type local:Weekdays}">
    <custControl:EnumName EnumValue="Monday" DisplayText="Mon" />
    <custControl:EnumName EnumValue="Tuesday" DisplayText="Tue" />
    <custControl:EnumName EnumValue="Wednesday" DisplayText="Wed" />
</custControl:EnumUINameCollection>
```

And below is the creation of custom control

```
<custControl:EnumChoiceControl Grid.Column="1"
                               custControl:EnumChoiceControlExtensions.OverrideEnumNames="{StaticResource daysUINamesOverridden}"
                               EnumType="{x:Type local:Weekdays}" />
```

**Question:**
How to make available of the intellisense during creation of StaticResource.
i.e. If we specify `EnumType`, then Xaml should provide us the enum names in intellisense while creating static resource.

Please suggest.

Comment: use enum values (`{x:Static local:Weekdays.Monday}`) instead of  strings (`"Monday"`). intellisense will show all enum options after typing `local:Weekdays.`

Comment: Sorry @ASh this doesn't show any intellisense. This works but doesn't show design time intellisense. Works only for static classes and static members within it.

Comment: Read this fellas [EDIT response in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596089/how-can-i-get-intellisense-to-auto-complete-an-enum-on-a-custom-user-control-in) as it sounds like what you're looking for.